# Access input value whitout losing focus

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I would like to access the value of an input of type text while i'm still focusing it to make change on the value. For the example to make the string `.ToUpper()` and see the change each time I enter a char.

Here is what I have for now:

```
<input value=@Result @onchange=@ToUpper />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private string Result;

    void ToUpper(ChangeEventArgs evt) {
        Result = evt.Value.ToString().ToUpper();
        Value = Result;
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
```

In this code, the string `Result` change `ToUpper` only after leaving the input.

What I don't want to do, is to apply some style to the input like : `style="text-transform: uppercase"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work...

```
<input type="text" @bind-value:event="oninput" @bind-value="ToUpper" />


@code {

    private string str;


    public string ToUpper
    {
        get
        {
            return str;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (str != value)
                str = value.ToUpper();

        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps...